# How can I set a simple hotkey(e.g. Alt+/) instead of Ctrl+Shift+O Shift+; to list function symbols in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use key shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+O Shift+;` to list function symbols in vscode frequently.

Is there a way to create a simple hotkey to replace it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own keyboard shortcuts in `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`, also available in the command palette, and with the shortcut `Ctrl+K Ctrl+S`.